# JVM 7 crashes due to a WMI dll

Tags: java, jvm, wmi, jvm-crash

I'm working with a Java Based product which is currently running using Java 7. The JVM crashes with the following error

> jvm 11   | # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   jvm 11   | #
>   jvm 11   | #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000f9816561, pid=1696, tid=3972
>   jvm 11   | #
>   jvm 11   | # JRE version: 7.0_05-b06
>   jvm 11   | # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.1-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 >compressed oops)
>   jvm 11   | # Problematic frame:
>   jvm 11   | # C  [WMIdll.dll+0x16561]  JNI_OnUnLoad+0x8f91
>   jvm 11   | #
>   jvm 11   | # Core dump written. Default location: E:\hp\UCMDB\DataFlowProbe\bin\hs_err_pid1696.mdmp
>   jvm 11   | #
>   jvm 11   | # An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   jvm 11   | # E:\hp\UCMDB\DataFlowProbe\bin\hs_err_pid1696.log
>   jvm 11   | #
>   jvm 11   | # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   jvm 11   | #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   jvm 11   | # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>   jvm 11   | # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>   jvm 11   | #
>   wrapper  | JVM exited unexpectedly.
>   wrapper  | There were 10 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
>   wrapper  |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
>   wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
>
> ---

I see this is happening due to a WMIdll.dll, and in the product logs I see a lot of errors relating to WMI. Basically the product is doing WMI queries to the remote machines to get data.

I have set the Heap size to 2 GB.  I see some related posts regarding the JVM crashes but I'm not able to make sense out of it. So any help here is appreciated.

BR

Comment: I'd get support from the vendor (HP?) here.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Same problem here with uCMDB 10.01 (CUP2).